Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://our-url/login' from origin 'https://our-url' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://back-end-url/login' from origin 'https://front-end-url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm running into CORS issues after I've upgraded my app from spring boot 3.3.2 to 3.3.3.
This our WebSecurityAuthConfig:
package com.dfs.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityAuthConfig {

    @Value("${dfs.security.oauth2.scope}")
    private String scope;

    @Value("${dfs.security.oauth2.resourceserver-uri}")
    private String url;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/**")
            .authenticated()).oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder()))
        );
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    //if scope is portal, then validate
    //TODO: decode the token and return the user role
    
    
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.url).build();
    }
}

And this is our CorsConfig:
package com.dfs.security.config;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.DELETE;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.PUT;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOriginPatterns("*.our-url.com")
            .allowedMethods(
                GET.name(),
                POST.name(),
                PUT.name(),
                DELETE.name()
            );
    }

}

And finally, this is our controller:
package com.dfs.api.feature.login;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import com.dfs.api.client.repository.dto.UserProfile;
import com.dfs.api.feature.login.dto.LoginResponse;

import com.dfs.logging.logger.HttpJsonLogger;

import static com.dfs.api.common.Constants.HEADER_PARAMS.NT_ACCOUNT;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/login")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private HttpJsonLogger logger;
    
    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login(@RequestHeader(name = NT_ACCOUNT) String ntAccount)
            throws ResponseStatusException {
    
        try {
            logger.debug("Getting User Profile", ntAccount);
            UserProfile userProfile = loginService.login(ntAccount);
    
            LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse(
                userProfile.role()
            );
    
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (ResponseStatusException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    
    }

}

we are using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server dependency on our pom.xml
It works when we downgrade it back to spring boot 3.3.2 but we have some vulnerabilities being reported on snyk that were fixed on spring boot 3.3.3.

seems to be duplicate question

Indeed @asgarov1, you can mark it as duplicated as defining the CORS as highest precedence worked for me.
Thanks a million!

This question is similar to: Spring Boot Restful Service and CORS problem. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

why not just check the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html

Because it was working fine with spring boot version 3.3.2.

If your app is not MVC and have backend and frontend in different app and you are using restful api to call backend than try doing this instead of WebvcConfigurer:
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("allowed_headers");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("allowed_methods");
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("frontend_url");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**",configuration);

        return source;
    }
}

and use this in SecurityFilterChain :
// Autowire this:
private final CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity
                    .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource))
                    ...
    }

Also remove @CrossOrigin annotation from your controller why do you need it when you have configured cors at global level.

thanks a lot for your answer @kush. Just a question on "configuration.addAllowedOrigin("frontend_url");" as we have this running on multiple environments (dev, pre-prod, prod). Do we need to add them all manually or is there a way to make it more generic?

there is another method that take list of origin you can pass it with environment variable or you can fetch this from your database when application starts but for this you have to restart your project every time you add new entry to database here is what method look like you can use it instead of addAllowedOrigin :          configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("urls that you want"));

Also there are similar method with set instead of add that takes list as parameter for methods, headers. like setAllowedHeaders.
